# Looking for testfunction pattern

Tags: python, unit-testing

I created some unittests for my project.

I got several classes with their own unittets.
But many test cases are similar in principle:

1. add something
2. get added elements
3. check this

For example:

```
Player.add_weapon("name")
Player.get_weapons()
for w in weapons:
 - check the validity bla bla

Warehouse.add_package("name")
Warehouse.get_packages()
for p in packages:
 - check the validity bla bla
```

You see, the context is different but the procedure the same.
This was my idea: (but maybe it exists a good pattern for this handling)

```
def mytestfunction(ut_instance, test_obj, add_method_as_string, getlist_method_as_string):
    add_obj = None
    get_obj_list = None    
    exec("add_obj=test_obj.%s" % add_method_as_string)        
    exec("get_obj_list=test_obj.%s" % getlist_method_as_string) 

    ut_instance.assertEqal(len(get_obj_list()), 0, msg="We need a empty test object")
    item = add_obj("lala")
    list = get_obj_list()

    #check this ..and so on ...
    ....
    pass
```

It works but maybe you know a smarter solution. For example to control the expectations or work with different parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't an inefficient factory method for tests; the problem is your underlying test paradigm. Unit testing should be checking the *behavior* of some object or method, not object composition.

Based on the sample you posted, I think you should be checking boundary conditions for your add and get methods, rather than focusing on whether certain values are present in a given data structure. Remember: behavior, not composition.

Testing is somewhat more of an art than a science. YMMV.